# Powershell UDP script works in ISE but not Console

Tags: sockets, powershell, console, udp, powershell-ise

First time attempting to work with UDP. I'm harvesting lat/long from a NMEA string in a UDP broadcast. The code below works fine in the ISE but hangs up in the console. I'm running both with Admin rights. Other posts on the topic recommend dot-sourcing, no difference. I suspect it's something to do with how it's handling variables but have hit a wall. Thanks in advance for help.

```
##########################################################################
#
# Read $GPGGA string from UDP broadcast on port 40181
#
# Convert Degree-Minutes-Seconds format to decimal lat/long
#
# UDP code harvested from http://winpowershell.blogspot.com/2010/01/powershell-udp-clientserver.html
#
# 
##########################################################################

# Form a connection point
$endpoint = New-Object system.net.ipendpoint([system.net.ipaddress]::Any,0)

Write-Host "Endpoint: " $endpoint

# Open UDP client
$udpclient = new-Object system.Net.Sockets.Udpclient(40181)

Write-Host "UDP client: " $udpclient

# Grab the datagram 
$content = $udpclient.Receive([ref]$endpoint)

Write-Host "Content: " $content

# Put the datagram in $udpstring as type string
$udpstring = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($content)

Write-Host "UDP string: " $udpstring

# Close UDP client
$udpclient.Close()

# Get Degree Min Sec format latitude from UDP string
# Explicit typing required in order to do math later
[Double]$DMSlatdeg = $udpstring.Substring(17,2)
$DMSlatmin = $udpstring.Substring(19,2)

# Get North South directional from UDP string
$directNS = $udpstring.Substring(29,1)

# Get Degree Min Sec format longitude from UDP string
# Explicit typing required in order to do math later
[Double]$DMSlongdeg = $udpstring.Substring(31,3)
$DMSlongmin = $udpstring.Substring(34,2)

# Get East West directional from UDP string
$directEW = $udpstring.Substring(44,1)

# Add decimal latitude minutes value to degrees
$declat = ($DMSlatdeg + ($DMSlatmin/60))

# Add decimal longitude minutes value to degrees
$declong = ($DMSlongdeg + ($DMSlongmin/60))

# Output formatted to three decimal places - variable value not changed
Write-Host "Decimal lat: " $declat.ToString("#.###") $directNS
Write-Host "Decimal long: " $declong.ToString("#.###") $directEW
```

In ISE I get the correct output:

Endpoint:  0.0.0.0:0

UDP client:  System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient

Content:  36 71 80 71 71 65 44 [etc]

UDP string:  $GPGGA,160516.13,[etc]

Decimal lat:  [correct value] N

Decimal long:  [correct value] W

In the console, it gets out the first two statements and hangs:

Endpoint:  0.0.0.0:0

UDP client:  System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient

Is there something wrong with the way I'm setting $content?

Comment: It's supposed to hang until data comes in from the network - "*The Receive method will block until a datagram arrives from a remote host.*" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - ISE does different things with regards to threading compared to the console, but I can't see any of that making any difference to receiving network data. Are you ... sure the data is coming in? Do you have some kind of firewall / AV software tool which allows ISE to host a server but forbids the powershell console?

Comment: Huzzah!! Windows Firewall was totally it - ISE was allowed and Powershell was blocked (don't know why but the problem is solved). Thanks!